# Difference between "to enter through", "to enter from", "to enter by"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Are all of the sentences below correct and usual? Do they mean the same?

- He entered the bedroom through the window.
- He entered the bedroom from the window.
- He entered the bedroom by the window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All three are possible and grammatically correct. However

> "He entered the bedroom through the window."

is by far the most common way of saying it. "Through" is associated with means of access to the bedroom, doors and windows, .

> "He entered the bedroom from the window."

would be more commonly used as

> "He entered the bedroom from the room next door"

as "from" implies he came from another place into the bedroom.

> "He entered the bedroom by the window"

probably needs some modification such as

> "He entered the bedroom by **opening** the window"

or

> "He entered the bedroom by **means of** the window"

otherwise it has a possible meaning of

> "He entered the bedroom **next to** the window"

which is possible, but not common.

A fourth, correct version is

> "He entered the bedroom **via** the window"

**via** having the same meaning as **through** in this case.